# How to make utility icons bigger?

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds

I understand you can set `size: large` for an icon, but is there a way to make them even bigger? I tried doing `size: 190px;` and `height: 190px; width: 190px;` for .my-icon and it does't seem to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting a width or height won't make them larger, as there's two layers to an image, the outer wrapper and the inner image, and the inner element can't be directly affected. You can only scale the outer element. If you want to make them larger, or smaller, use `zoom`:

```
<lightning-icon icon-name="utility:up" style="zoom: 800%"></lightning-icon>
```

Or, you can use transform, but you'll have to both scale and translate it in order for it to be positioned correctly.

[Demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/fZTOQ6t82SaWvaUf8F77/src/app.html).